# Having trouble with local central repository, pulling and pushing changes from another local location

Tags: git

I'm playing around with Git, I've created a text file called `test.txt` with a simple string in it "Hello". If we can pretend that multiple users log into the same computer but each wants to branch off from a central repo, make changes then push back to it:

`Users/Ari/MyCentralRepo/test.txt`

I go into `MyCentralRepo` and initialise it as a repository and add the file.

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit 'first commit'
```

Now for the sake of pretending I'm another user who can access the above directory as well, but I want to clone the project, I would do:

```
$ git clone Users/Ari/MyCentralRepo -- Users/JohnSmith/Dev_branch01
```

This creates a clone of the repo the use John Smith can work on without affecting the `MyCentralRepo`

John Smith makes some changes to the `test.txt` file, "Hello world!"
    $ git status
    # shows there has been a change to test.txt
    $ git add .
    $ git commit -m 'Added more text'

How does John Smith push the changes back to Users/Ari/MyCentralRepo? Does it have something to do with `git remote`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John would have to "push" into the other user's repo. When cloning, the repo from which you cloned is set up as a remote called "origin"... so john would have to do something like `git push origin master`. The only thing is that because origin is a "real" repo (not a bare one), git will probably reject the push operation if the original user has branch master checked out (that's another question altogether). John could try something like `git push origin master:john-branch` and then you would end up with a second branch on the original remote.

**Advice:
Set up a central bare repo and let users interact with it.**

Create a third repo that's bare:

```
git init --bare some-location-on-your-fs/central
```

Then, go to each developer and add this repo as a remote. The first developer (Ari?) could push master there:

```
git remote add central-repo path-to-central-repo # done by both developers
git push central master # done by Ari
```

Make John see what's on central:

```
git fetch central-repo
git push central-repo master # john is pushing his master branch into the central repo
```

Then Ari could see those changes and work from there

```
git fetch central-repo
git merge central-repo/master
```

**Side note**: I don't use pull so that you can see what's going on step by step... pull can introduce a number of misconceptions if you don't know exactly what it does.

Comment: Ahh, yeah thats the issue I'm running into at the moment. I'm trying `git push` and `git push origin master` and I'm getting some errors saying it can't. What is the best way to go about doing this? Central local repo, multiple users working on their own version and pushing back to the central repo locally?

Comment: when using a central repo _with pushing_ like you are trying, normally the central repo is a _bare_ repo so that there's no real user sitting there working.

Comment: Then users would be able to push. Perhaps you should create a new repo?Let me add the instructions on my answer so you can continue from there,

Comment: I found a tutorial, so instead of using the MyCentralRepo directly, I've clones it to a bare repo, then for each user clones from the bare repo. But when push user changes, the bare repo or the MyCentralRepo files aren't updated? Do I need to manually pull?

Comment: A bare repo has no "working tree", the only thing it holds is a git repo (it's database, metadata, etc)... so don't expect to see the files that you have on the project to show up there and update every time you push.

Comment: Oh I see now! I made another pretend user, cloned the bare repo and the edited file was cloned. Thanks, appreciate the help.